# C++ Boost::Thread & Boost::ASIO memory leak

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio

I got one problem in my code.

When connection finishes there is 10 megabytes ram leak everyone connection.

Connection work propertly, and packet sended is valid.

I don't know where is wrong.

Worker function :

```
    void worker(boost::shared_ptr<CConnection> connection) 
{
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket &socket = *(connection->socket);
    boost::asio::socket_base::non_blocking_io make_non_blocking(true);
    socket.io_control(make_non_blocking);

    while ( connection->close == false ) {

    char * buffer = new char[16]();
    buffer[0] = 16;
    buffer[4] = 1;
    buffer[8] = 1;
    buffer[12] = 1;

    boost::asio::async_write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(buffer, 16), boost::bind(handle_write, buffer));
    connection->close = true;
    } // while connection not to be closed
    LOG(INFO, "Connection finished!");
    socket.shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both);
    socket.close();
}
```

Acceptor code :

```
void CCore::handle_accept(const boost::system::error_code& error) 
{
    if (error) {
        // accept failed
        LOG(ERROR, "Acceptor failed: " << error.message());
        return;
    }

    LOG(INFO, "Accepted connection from " << this->connection->endpoint.address().to_string() << ":" << this->connection->endpoint.port());

    this->connection->thread = boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread>(new boost::thread(worker, this->connection));

    this->connection = boost::shared_ptr<CConnection>(new CConnection());
    this->connection->master_io_service = this->io_service;
    this->acceptor->async_accept(*(this->connection->socket), this->connection->endpoint, boost::bind(&CCore::handle_accept, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}
```

Connection definition :

```
class CConnection {
  public:
    CConnection(void);
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint;
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> thread;
    boost::asio::io_service *master_io_service;

    bool close;
};
```

Packet data is freed in handle_write by :

```
void handle_write(char * buf)
{
 delete [] buf;
}
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer.html) boost::asio::buffer doesn't own the memory it points to, therefore your buffer which you `new[]` up leaks as there's no matching `delete[]`.

Again, according to that page its your responsiblility to make sure that it remains alive and then `delete[]` it afterwards.

Comment: Memory is freed in handle write from packet data.

Answer (score 1):

In the worker thread you allocate memory in every loop, but you never free it.

You can either use [smart pointers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm), or pass the pointer as an argument to the async write habndler function and free it there.

Comment: Memory is freed in handle_write : delete [] buf;

Comment: @KacperFałat Then you should state that in the question, as it's not obvious.

Answer (score 1):

The write buffer's memory management looks fine.  There is a circular reference between `CConnection` and `CConnection::thread`:

- `CConnection::thread`'s lifespan depends on `CConnection` as it is a member variable.
- `CConnection`'s lifespan indirectly depends on `CConnection::thread` due to `CConnection` being bound as an argument to the `boost::thread`'s constructor.  The lifespan of this argument is coupled to the lifespan of the `boost::thread` object, and not the execution of the underlying thread.

  ```
  void CCore::handle_accept(...) 
  {
    ...

    this->connection->thread = 
      boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread>(new boost::thread(worker,
                                                         this->connection));
    ...
  }
  ```

Removing the circular reference should allow for proper cleanup.  It is not clear to me as to what the expected lifespan of the objects are, so I cannot provide an exact solution.

---

Also, some of the Boost.Asio handling looks a bit awkward to me.  It looks as though it is mixing synchronous and asynchronous behaviors, which can be very difficult to accomplish.  In this case, it could be possible for the the `async_write` operation to be is canceled before completion.  Consider synchronizing state between `worker` and `handle_write`, and setting the close state from within `handle_write`.